# Residual error for Runge-kutta method

Tags: differential-equations

I am using the below code for residual error for nonlinear ODE using Runge-Kutta method:

```
   ClearAll["Global`*"]

     β = 0.5; m = 0.3;

      ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, prec_] := 
       With[{amat = {{1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
       bvec = {1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6}, cvec = {1/2, 1/2, 1}}, 
       N[{amat, bvec, cvec}, prec]]
       {yf} = {y} /. 
       First@NDSolve[{y'[x] + 2 β*(y'[x])^3 - m*(x - 1) == 0, 
       y[0] == 1}, {y}, {x, 0, 1}, 
       Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
        "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients}, 
        StartingStepSize -> 0.1];
 

         residual[x_] = y'[x] + 2 β*(y'[x])^3 - m*(x - 1);

        er1 = Abs[{residual[x] /. y -> yf}];

        LogPlot[er1, {x, 0, 1}]

        x = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1};

          er1

         {{5.55112*10^-17, 2.22045*10^-16, 4.57757*10^-16, 
         4.96507*10^-16, 0., 2.37144*10^-16, 4.65268*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, 
          4.8473*10^-16, 3.50053*10^-16, 2.48253*10^-16}}

          y1 = Max[er1]

           4.96507*10^-16
```

The problem is the error range in the plot is not the same as numerical values even for the same values of x? Why?

Thanks

Comment: The two are the same,  Check out `yf["Grid"]` and note that the residual error at a step is theoretically ***zero*** (and in practice it just round-off error from evaluating the terms of the residual).  The larger deviations in the error plot are from interpolation error between the steps.  The residual is not a very good measure of error in numerical ODE solving (although there may be some early answers from me using it before I appreciated this).

Comment: Dear Michael E2, is not the same the accuracy of plot up to 10^-6, but for numerical value up to 10^-16?

Comment: Hi, 10^-6 is the error due to interpolation between the steps.  Try a different `x` to see the agreement, say, `x = Subdivide[0., 1., 50]`.  The degree of the interpolation is 3 by default, and the error is similar to a cubic polynomial: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AnTha.png,  If you add the option `InterpolationOrder -> All`, the degree will be 4 (equal to the `"DifferenceOrder"`) and the error will resemble a quartic polynomial: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rEcu4.png

Comment: Dear Michael E2, many thanks for your very useful comments, now it is clear to me. Best regards